# what is wrong this scheme code?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I'm studying sicp. 
this question is ex 1.3.
I can't understand why this code is problem.
please help me.. TT

here's the code.

```
(define (test a b c)
        (cond ((and (< a b) (< a c)) (+ (* b b) (* c c))
               (and (< b a) (< b c)) (+ (* a a) (* c c))
               (else (+ (* b b) (* c c)))
        ))

(test 1 2 3)
```

error is

> Premature EOF on #[input-port 60 from buffer at #[mark 61 #[buffer 17]
>   166 left]

Comment: You seem to have a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for `cond` is wrong. Here is the same code with the correct syntax:

```
(define (test a b c)
  (cond ((and (< a b) (< a c)) (+ (* b b) (* c c)))
        ((and (< b a) (< b c)) (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
        (else (+ (* b b) (* c c)))))
```

However, your code is still wrong. Can you see why? (Hint: what does the `else` branch signify, and what expression should be there?)

Comment: I fixed code. thanx!! But I don't understand what is still wrong.

Comment: Test with a case where `c` is the smallest number.

Comment: oops!! (else (+ (* a a) (* b b))))) I missed it!! thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Missing parentheses.

```
(define
  (test a b c)
  (cond
    ((and (< a b) (< a c)) (+ (* b b) (* c c)))
    ((and (< b a) (< b c)) (+ (* a a) (* c c)))
    (else (+ (* b b) (* c c))))
```